# Access external HDD on Ubuntu Pc via Mac Book

Tags: mount, hard-drive, mac, drive

I am running Ubuntu 16.06 on a small PC, to which I have an external HDD attached.
I would  like to access this external hard drive via a MacBook running OSX (via WiFi).

I have shared the folders (including the external HD) on the Ubuntu machine in the network and I have access to the home directory of the Ubuntu machine from the Finder on the Mac. But I am unable to access the exernal hard drive.
Does anyone have an idea on how I could do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to share the external hard drive using the "Files" program in Ubuntu?

Comment: do you mean Nautilus? yes, the external HD is shared in the local network, but doesn't show up on the mac.
And a link to the folder doesn't work in the Mac. It work on another Ubuntu machine, but not on the Mac.

Comment: Make sure the mount point of the external hard drive has the right read and write permission. That is, anyone can read and write to the external hard drive when it is mounted on the Ubuntu computer. This is needed along with making it shareable in Nautilus.